# Question about Rayleigh-Jeans law derivation

Tags: electromagnetic-radiation, wavefunction, thermal-radiation

I'm trying to understand the derivation of Rayleigh-Jeans law of this following video:
https://youtu.be/rCfPQLVzus4?t=1142

And there are some parts that I'm still not clear:

- When he derive the number of states $N(f)df=\frac{4L}{c}df$. Why isn't it be just $N(f)$, what is the purpose of $df$? If so, is $N(f)=\frac{4L}{c}$? Furthermore, do the number of states must take integer value?

Comment: The df is important to keep in both mind and in the notation, because the derived resulting distribution law has many different possible viewpoints, each with a different form, because we are stuck with bad notation. Number of states ought to be integer, but will fail to be in this infinitesimal form.